# Graphing Time series in python using consistent hourly markings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

So my data looks can be found in the link below. I am trying to graph the time series with hourly marking. Basically draw the major marks at the top of the hour for example 20:00,21:00,22:00,23:00 and minor marks halfway through the hour for example 20:30,21:30,22:30,23:30.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g2UhLBhddWSxuH6bnFT3kMO90ZDEQT5F6fF_GTNPk_w

The date column Date is converted to a datetime while the time column is left untouched.

My data is in CSV files and I currently read it into a data frame and graph them using the command below.

```
df.plot(kind='line', x= "Time_split",y= "Total_S4_Sig1")
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

This does not quite achieve what I am trying to do as.

Thank you for your time in advance. I really appreciate your help.

With respect,
Chintan Thakrar

Comment: Could you show your plot and describe a bit further what you are trying to achieve? So far I don't understand your goal

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your `Date` and `Time_split` into one timestamp column and plot with `HourLocator` and `MinuteLocator`:

```
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time_split'])

ax=df.plot(x='time', y='Total_S4_Sig1')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(30))
```

Comment: Could you please explain what mdates is?

Comment: What is my “Time_split” variable is of time datetime, it’s giving me an error ever time I try to convert it to delta time. Do you have an alternative using the datetime of the “Time_split” we could even work with datetime.dt.time.

Comment: Please advise. I would really appreciate your help. I have spent literally hours trying to fix it.

Comment: Your sample data shows that `Time_split` is just string `01:00:00`, why don't you parse it as `timedelta` and not `datetime`?

Comment: oh God @Quang Hoang. The data is of time datetime because I do some preprocessing before plotting. I commented the code that did the datetime conversion just to try your plotting method. I am getting an error. ValueError: only leading negative signs are allowed. I dont see how deltatime can be negative. Please advise. Again thank you so much for replying. This thing has literally screwed me up for hours and I am super frustrated.